# There is no Rewrapper flag for authentication settings. But Authentication Type required

Tags: chromium, bazel

With this configuration file :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~/chromium-original/chromium/src/buildtools/reclient/bb-deployments/bare# cat reclientConfigBBFrontend.txt 
service=127.0.0.1:8980
instance=$RE_SERVER_INSTANCE
log_dir=/tmp
output_dir=/tmp
proxy_log_dir=/tmp
depsscanner_address=$scandeps_server_location #distributed with Reclient
```

I get this error : `Unable to authenticate with RBE service needs to be specified, authentication type (identity) used="unknown authentication type` :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~/chromium-original/chromium/src/buildtools/reclient/bb-deployments/bare# ../../rewrapper -cfg=reclientConfigBBFrontend.txt -platform=OSFamily=linux,ISA=x86-64,docker=//gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/rbe-ubuntu16-04@sha256:b4dad0bfc4951d619229ab15343a311f2415a16ef83bcaa55b44f4e2bf1cf635 -exec_strategy="remote_local_fallback" -dial_timeout="10m" -exec_root="/root/chromium-original/chromium/src" -- /root/tmp/bb-cache/
F1010 12:59:21.831161  377524 main.go:175] Command failed: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = Unable to authenticate with RBE
service needs to be specified, authentication type (identity) used="unknown authentication type"
```

But in `Rewrapper` flags there is no flag for authentication settings : https://github.com/bazelbuild/reclient/blob/main/docs/cmd-line-flags.md#rewrapper

O.S. : Ubuntu 22.04

Since according to https://github.com/bazelbuild/reclient/blob/main/docs/cmd-line-flags.md#notes-on-credentials-and-authentication-source one of these flags :

```
credential_file,
use_application_default_credentials,
use_gce_credentials
```

is mandatory,

how to define the `credental_file`, for a **self-hosted buildbarn remote instance** to work?